# redirect_to not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
unless current_user.owns_photo? @photo
  redirect_to photos_path
end
```

I have code like this when i run the application if current photo isn't owned by the owner it will redirect the user to the path of photos. However when i run the same set of code but add return to it:

```
unless current_user.owns_photo? @photo
  redirect_to photos_path && return
end
```

it causes irregular results. The authenticated user can continue to see things that do not belong to them. However when i drop the return it works fine. Why isn't it working with the return? I heard it is good practice to have return when using redirect_to so it does not execute any more code after.

```
def owns_photo?(photo)
  photos.include? photo
end
```

That is the method for owns_photo that works properly. I am just curious about this return issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `redirect_to photos_path and return`. Use `and` instead of `&&`. Those operators has different priorities.

Typing `redirect_to photos_path && return` means `redirect_to (photos_path && return)`, while `redirect_to photos_path and return` means `(redirect_to photos_path) and return`

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with [Ruby Operator Precedence](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Operator_Precedence)

`&&` (Logical `AND`) operator has higher precedence than `and` (Logical composition) operator.

So, when you write this: `redirect_to photos_path && return`, this is interpreted as: `redirect_to (photos_path && return)` which is not what you want.

To solve this issue, you can do two things, either (use parentheses while using `&&` operator):

```
(redirect_to photos_path) && return
```

or, use `and` operator which is normally used in such cases in Rails (see [this post](http://blog.arkency.com/2014/07/4-ways-to-early-return-from-a-rails-controller/)):

```
redirect_to photos_path and return
```

Both of these should work as expected and should solve your problem.